# Java: Find Integers in a String (Calculator)

Tags: java

If I have a `String` that looks like this: `String calc = "5+3"`. Can I substring the `integers` `5` and `3`?

In this case, you do know how the String looks, but it could look like this: `String calc = "55-23"` Therefore, I want to know if there is a way to identify integers in a String.

Comment: Use split() function.

Comment: Use regex : To identify integers in a String - regex-  "\\d+"

Comment: What is the purpose of just finding the numbers and ignoring the rest of the string?

Comment: @Playdowin I really recommend reading up on the `Matcher` class.  The two good answers that are currently here both use it, but it's really good to know all of its ins and outs.

Comment: Also, it's interesting to me that although Playdowin specified "integers", the answers that have been posted so far only deal with non-negative integers, and are therefore ALL technically incorrect.

Comment: @DavidWallace That's because differentiating a minus binary operator from a minus unary operator, aka a sign, requires a parser, and the operator is not technically part of the integer literal.

Comment: An integer is an integer. No matter what you call the minus sign at the front, it's still part of the integer.

Comment: @DavidWallace This is valid Java: `int x = 5+-+-+-+-7;` and is the value `12`. Does `7` have a sign, or is this a `+` binary operator, and 7 unary operators between the `5` and `7` literals?

Comment: @Andreas What difference does it make?  OP asked how to identify integers in a string.  Some integers are negative.

Comment: @DavidWallace You are the one who claimed that the answers were "incorrect", so the difference matters. If you define the weird expression I gave as integer `7` with 7 unary operators, then the answers are correct. If you define that it should be `-7` with 6 unary operators, then you are right. The definition definitely matters, and you assumed one definition categorically, without consideration of potential requirement/definition.

Comment: @Andreas OP never said that their expressions `"String calc = 5+3"` and `"String calc = 55-23"` were Java statements.  They only said that these are strings in which they wish to identify the integers.  Presumably, if one such expression were `"String calc = -55+-42"`, they'd want to identify `-55` and `-42`, both of which are integers.  All the talk of unary and binary operators is a red herring.  This is about identifying integers, positive and negative, in a string; and _still_ nobody has answered the question correctly.

Comment: @DavidWallace You are again *assuming* that OP wants `-42` as an answer. That has not been stated either way, so we can discuss this until we die and never know for sure. Answers may or may not be correct, that's for OP to decide, not you or me, so you can't categorically say answers are incorrect. That was the only point I was trying to make

Comment: If the OP _doesn't_ want `-42` as an answer, then they have asked a question that's different from what they wanted.  They clearly said that they want integers.  I believe that on SO, we should answer the question that's asked, not the question that the OP was thinking of when they asked it.

Comment: Can we assume that no one actually cares and accept the fact OP accepted the answer and stop or take this to a private trolling session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like that, regular expression is your friend:

```
String text = "String calc = 55-23";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(text);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

*Output*

```
55
23
```

---

Now, you might need to expand it to support decimals:

```
String text = "String calc = 1.1 + 22 * 333 / (4444 - 55555)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:.\\d+)?").matcher(text);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

*Output*

```
1.1
22
333
4444
55555
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read each character and find it's Ascii code. Evaluate its code if it is between 48 and 57, it is a number and if it is not, it is a symbol.
if you find another character that is a number also you must add to previous number until you reach a symbol.

```
    String calc="55-23";
    String intString="";
    char tempChar;
    for (int i=0;i<calc.length();i++){
        tempChar=calc.charAt(i);
        int ascii=(int) tempChar;
        if (ascii>47 && ascii <58){
            intString=intString+tempChar;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(intString);
            intString="";
            }
    }
```

Comment: There are easier ways to do it with Regular Expressions

Comment: @YassinHajaj, I'm willing to guess if OP knew what regex were they wouldn't have needed to ask the question.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils the point is to give the most accurate answer while having OP learning new concepts at the same time...

Comment: @YassinHajaj, not to nitpick but the site says this - " Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer." Doesn't mention anything about teaching anyone new concepts.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes, it does.  But this is not "the right direction".

Comment: @DavidWallace, that's just your opinion. Is it possible or not to to determine if a character is numeric by its ascii value? If yes, then it's not the "wrong" direction. The "right direction" is any direction that can lead to a correct answer. The fact remains the comment that was in response to was wrong and proven so by the help reference.

Comment: I actually agree with David. It is always better to use robust frameworks/libraries, like regular expression implementations, than trying to handle all edge cases by yourself. Does this code handle all edge cases on all platforms? We don't know because it isn't tested by thousands of people over multiple years.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex like `([\d]+)([+-])([\d]+)` to obtain the full binary expression.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\d]+)([+-])([\\d]+)");

String calc = "5+3";

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(calc);

if (matcher.matches()) {

    int lhs = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int rhs = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));

    char operator = matcher.group(2).charAt(0);

    System.out.print(lhs + " " + operator + " " + rhs + " = ");

    switch (operator) {

        case '+': {
            System.out.println(lhs + rhs);
        }

        case '-': {
            System.out.println(lhs - rhs);
        } 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5 + 3 = 8
```